# How to check if Pandas/NumPy arbitrary object contains or IS NaT/NaN/Null

Tags: python, pandas, null

I want to check if a Pandas object is/contains any Null/NaN/NaT value, but I have no information beforehand if the object is a list or one singular value.

I tried

```
x = [1,2,3,pd.NaT]
if pd.notnull(x):
    ...
```

But if the object `x` is a list, it returns this value error (due to it returning an array of boolean values):

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

And if I do this:

```
x = pd.NaT
if pd.notnull(x).any():
   ...
```

It returns this error if I receive a singular value:

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'
```

What's the cleanest way to go about this that is capable of dealing with both lists that may contain NaN's AND NaN's themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `x` inside of list and pass to `pd.notna` and chain `any`. It works because `pd.notna` returns numpy ndarray. Therefore, the `any` is actually `ndarray.any`. The When calling numpy `ndarray.any` with out `axis` parameter, it will check on all dimensions. Therefore, it works on both list `x` or single value `x`

```
x = [1,2,3,pd.NaT]

In [369]: pd.notna([x])
Out[369]: array([[ True,  True,  True, False]]) #it is 2d-array

In [370]: type(pd.notna([x]))
Out[370]: numpy.ndarray

In [373]: pd.notna([x]).any()  #`ndarray.any` checks on all dimensions of this 2d-array
Out[373]: True

In [374]: pd.notna([x]).all()  #`ndarray.all` checks on all dimensions of this 2d-array
Out[374]: False
```

On `x` is single `pd.NaT`

```
x = pd.NaT

In [377]: pd.notna([x])
Out[377]: array([False])  #it is 1d-array

In [378]: pd.notna([x]).any()
Out[378]: False

In [379]: pd.notna([x]).all()
Out[379]: False
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. For my purposes, chaining with ```all()``` not ```any()``` is what I need.

Comment: One thing to note though, it doesn't work for embedded lists. E.g. ```x = [1,2,3,[1,pd.NaT]]```

Comment: yeah, it doesn't work on embedded list because `pd.notna` doesn't recursively check nested elements. In the embedded lists, it considers each sublist as a whole element, so unless the sublist is empty, it returns `True` on the sublist.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to know if any value in your dataframe is a `NaN`, then you can simply do

```
if df.isnull().any().any():
    # NaN present(s)
    do_something()
```